# How to get params and query params from url in angular 9

Tags: angular

I have a url , I want to get params and queryparams both and each request parameter should be separated out using '&' except first one.First one will be separated by '?' For Ex
Request URL:abc.com/abc:abc:abc:0xa35df9cdf?ab=1234567?lang=en
I should get in variable
let result = abc:abc:abc:0xa35df9cdf?ab=1234567&lang=en , I have used this, but I need in a single variable and also dynamic, my query param can be multiple

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
  
this.route.params.subscribe((param: any) => { console.log(param) })
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param: any) => { console.log(param) })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future please be more clear about what you want to do, you have to use some sort of http get function and get the url first, then pipe the results starting one by one till you get to the end. this allows you to separate the variables.

```
string1 ?: string;
string2 ?: string;

this.httpClient.get(getRoute).pipe(map(c => {
  c = c,
  //convert to unknown because we don't know how the format will be helps    //with enum values
  this.string1=c?.abc as unknown as string,
  this.string2=c?.xyx as unknown as string
  publishReplay(1), // this tells Rx to cache the latest emitted
  refCount();

  }
  )
).subscribe((d) => {
  const url = yoururl + '&' + this.string1 + '&' this.string2
  this.httpClient.post(url,{}).subscribe((results)=>{
    console.log(results)
  })
 // removed the routes interface, not relevant
});
```